# How to add HTML content in both head and body sections in Play Framework?

Tags: java, scala, playframework

While using `Play Framework 2`, I often use a "master page" (*main.scala.html*) where I leave part of the body to be added later by another page (let's say *content.scala.html*).

It has happened to me (several times) that  page I want to add some HTML to the head (such as *.css* files) in a concrete page which uses the main. How could I call the "master page" with both HTML parts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an additional parameter at the end in the main file ([sample in documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaTemplateUseCases#moreScripts-and-moreStyles-equivalents))

```
@(param1: String, moreHeaders = Html(""))(content)
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Your default headers here -->
        @moreHeaders
    </head>
    <body>
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

and then in the files you need to add additional headers you define them using a variable:

```
@moreHeaders = {
    <script src="path/to/file.js"></script>
    <!-- (...) -->    
}

@main("First parameter", moreHeaders) {
    <p>Hi</p>    
}
```

As the moreHeaders has a default value, when you dont want to add additional headers you can just omit it:

```
@("First parameter") {
    <p>Hi</p>    
}
```